# Joint Posterior for Binomial Likelihood and Beta Priors

Tags: bayesian, prior, posterior, conjugate-prior

Suppose we have the likelihood for known $n$

$$\mathbf{x} \vert p,k \sim \mathrm{Binomial}(n, kp)$$
with a beta prior for $p$ with known parameters $a$ and $b$

$$p \sim \mathrm{Beta}(a, b)$$

and independently a uniform prior [or Beta(1,1)] for $k$

$$k \sim \mathrm{Beta}(1, 1).$$

What would the joint posterior distribution for $p$ and $k$ given our data, $\mathbf{x}$, look like? The confusion I have here is that once proceeding as usual, we have (for one individual observation $x$)

$$\mathrm{posterior} \propto (kp)^x(1-kp)^{n-x}p^{a-1}(1-p)^{b-1}$$

From here, I can't seem to figure out the joint posterior pdf. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You might start by find a prior for $q=kp$, and then use $\mathbf{x} \vert p,k \sim \mathrm{Binomial}(n, q)$ to find a posterior distribution for $q$.  But you you not expect this is be simple as $q$ does not have a Beta distribution and so you are not using a conjugate family.  For example, if $a=b=1$ then the prior density for $q$ is $-\log_e(q)$.